# IIS6 & PHP: How to enable partent paths?

Tags: windows-server-2003, mysql, php, iis

I have Windows 2003 server with IIS 6, PHP, and MYSQL all running correctly but when installing `phpMyAdmin` I get the following errors:

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php) [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\mysql.mydomain.com.au\index.php on line 35

PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required './libraries/common.inc.php' (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\mysql.mydomain.com.au\index.php on line 35
```

Obviously it's saying it can't find the `required_once()` path because parent paths (ie "./") isn't enabled for some reason.

Does anyone know a workaround for this with having to resort to editing code in `phpMyAdmin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Obviously it's saying it can't find the required_once() path because parent paths (ie "./") isn't enabled for some reason

No - the parent path is '..' not '.' (the latter references the CWD).

Do you have a directory

```
C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\mysql.mydomain.com.au\libraries
```

If not, something has gone wrong with your installation. If the directory is there, then its most likely a permissions issue.

Comment: Erm, yes your right it is the cwd. The directories are all there and with the correct permissions.

Comment: That's very odd - try running a script to see the output of getcwd(), file_exists(), is_dir() and is_readable() for 'libraries','./libraries', 'libraries/common.inc.php' and './libraries/common.inc.php' run from the same dir as index.php